# Data migration Tool sales rule actions and condition serialized

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, sales-rule

I'm using Magento Data migration tool to migrate Magento 1.9.3 to Magento 2.3.4, everything went fine until I check the log error when I went to checkout page, I found out that in sales_rule table there is a Magento 1 class in Actions Serialized and Conditions Serialized there is a class from my custom extension that has not been converted:

```
...,{"type":"vendor_module\/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales",...
```

I tried to convert it by using Data Migration Tool `class-map.xml` but still no luck

```
<rename>
 <from>vendor_module/rule_condition_product_onsales_onsales</from>
 <to>Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Onsales\Onsales</to>
</rename>
```